# jQuery mobile styles are not getting applied over dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile-application

I have jQuery mobile app in which when users successfully logs in I have to show multi-page template content loaded through Ajax and json parsing dynamically. So there are two problems

1.Is these approach correct call ajax on document ready function for dynamic content generation.

2.when the content is getting generated dynamically jQuery mobile Styles are not coming over it.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css" />
<script src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $
                .ajax({
                    url : "demourl.com",
                    type : "GET",
                    success : function(data) {
                        var msgData = $.parseJSON(data);                

                            $("<div data-role='page'>").appendTo("#pageData")
                                    .trigger("create");
                            $("<div data-role='header'>").appendTo("#pageData")
                                    .trigger("create");
                            $("<h1>Page Title</h1>").appendTo("#pageData")
                                    .trigger("create");
                            $("<div>").appendTo("#pageData").trigger("create");
                            $("<div>").appendTo("#pageData").trigger("create");                     

                    }
                });

    });
</script>
<title>Message list</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="pageData"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not going to work.

jQuery Mobile requires at least one predefined page to work correctly.

No matter are you using trigger('create') or trigger('pagecreate') to enhance new page markup, those functions will fail without unless there's at least one regular jQM page.

But you can cheat, instead of letting jQM enhancing your first dynamic page you do it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/smsnP/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<div id="index" data-role="page" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 386px;"><div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner"><h3 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">First Page</h3></div></div>').appendTo("body");
});
```

Comment: you example is working but I have to fetch data from ajav then I have tgo built the page. If am using your function like these

Comment: I gave you an example in your other question. Also with or without ajax is not going to matter here, point is, you can't create and style jQuery Mobile page without at least one existing page. My example here is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this on your page:

```
 $('#pageData').page('refresh', true);
```

It should trigger the elements to render jquery mobile style.

Comment: Try binding with $(document).pagecreate(); instead (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html). ready does not work properly with JQM.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's working for me: 
-first, load data you need with ajax ($.ajax, $.post,..)
-after data is received, load jquery mobile script

this code work for me:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-docs.css" />
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $.post(url,
         {param: var},
         function(data){
            if( data.success )
            {
               $("#total_marcatges").append(data.total);
               $("#marcatges").append(data.marcatges);
               $.getScript('js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js', function() {
                   $("#sortir span span.ui-btn-text").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
               });
            }else
            {
               alert("error");
            }
        },
        "json"
);
```

after that, the jquery mobile styles are apllied for me